some area of drawerlayer is invisible but clickable after pause VideoView at android tv
I am developing an Android app that can play videos. While using VideoView to play videos, I encountered a bug where part of the navigation using DrawerLayout is not visible but clickable after the video is paused. The navigation works fine until the video is paused. Is there a solution?
Below is the code snippet I’m currently working on.
Activity part

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_list);

        navWrap = findViewById(R.id.nav_wrap);

        initNavigation();
        initVideoView();
        initEvent();

        playButton = findViewById(R.id.play_btn);
    }

    public void initNavigation(){
        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        if (!drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT)) {
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT) ;
        }
    }

    public void initVideoView(){
        videoView = findViewById(R.id.video_view);
        videoView.setVideoPath("url");

        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(mp -> {
            mp.setLooping(true);
            mp.setVolume(0, 0);
            mp.start();
        });
    }

    public void initEvent(){
        playButtonWrap = findViewById(R.id.play_btn_layout);
        playButtonWrap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (videoView.isPlaying()) {
                    stopVideo();
                } else {
                    startVideo();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void startVideo(){
        //video start
        videoView.start();
        //btn image change
        changeBtn(true);
    }
    public void stopVideo(){
        //video stop
        videoView.pause();
        //btn image change
        changeBtn(false);
    }

    private void changeBtn(boolean isPlaying){
        playButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        navWrap.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        playButton.setImageDrawable(isPlaying ? getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.start) : getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pause));
        fadeOutAndHideImage(playButton);
    }

layout part
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".UI.PlayListActivity"
        android:background="@color/background_grey"
        >
        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/video_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/play_btn_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/play_btn"
                android:layout_width="250px"
                android:layout_height="250px"
                android:background="@drawable/play_btn_background"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:src="@drawable/start"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:scaleY=".8"
                android:scaleX=".8"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:clickable="true"
                />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:background="@color/thumb_background_black"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/thumbnail_wrap_padding"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/thumbnail_wrap_padding"
            >
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/thumbnail_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="120px"
                android:layout_marginEnd="120px"
                />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/playlist_prev_btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/zxing_transparent"
                android:src="@drawable/prev"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/thumbnail_recycler_view"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/playlist_next_btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/thumbnail_recycler_view"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:src="@drawable/next"
                android:background="@color/zxing_transparent"
                />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    <include layout="@layout/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

picture when normal

picture when bug

tv uses android api 25
how can i fix it? do you have any idea?
